# How do i select rows displayed in current page in datatables 1.9?

Tags: jquery, datatables, legacy

I am using datatable 1.9 along with tabletool.js 2.1.5.
I have 23 records in total and 10 records per page. I want to select the currently displaying page records.

I have used TableTools.js buttons (select_all). But this selects all the rows of datatable.
I have tried

```
$('#file-records> tbody > tr').each(function() {                                
   TableTools.fnGetInstance('file-records').fnSelect($(this));                                              
});
```

The above code gives me an error
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nTr' of undefined**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented the following

```
$('#file-records> tbody > tr').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

$(this).addClass("active"); adds a background-color: #017ebc that i have written in the css file.

so when you want to get the selected row value you can have

```
$('#file-records> tbody > tr').each(function() {
     if($(this).hasClass('active')){
     console.log($(this)[0]);
   }
});
```

$(this)[0] is the row attribute for me, from which we can get the actual row contents